# Accessing sub of sub fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

how can I get access to sub of sub field in acf php?
for example I have filed of "team" and subfield of "name"

company->team members -> name

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that:

```
$data = get_field('company', $post->ID);
echo esc_html($data['team_members']['name']);
```